# where did the lfe package go and how can I find out about things like that?

Tags: r

I'm looking for an updated version of this:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/lfe/index.html
package. It seems to have been removed from CRAN. How could I find out about the history of this process to maybe find out if it was migrated to a new package or just isn't maintained anymore?

Comment: https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/issues/41

Comment: That link is in my answer ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The package was back on CRAN on 11 January 2021. It has been updated several times since.

---

The page you linked provides some information:

> Package ‘lfe’ was removed from the CRAN repository.
> Formerly available versions can be obtained from the archive.
> Archived on 2020-12-04 as check problems were not corrected in time.

My conclusions:

- as of today (11 Dec 2020), it was removed only a week ago (Dec 4)
- it appears to have been archived by CRAN maintainers, not withdrawn by package authors/maintainers.
- if we go to the page and [retrieve the most recent version](https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/lfe/lfe_2.8-5.1.tar.gz) (2.8-5.1, 2020-07-08) and open the `DESCRIPTION` file in the archive, we can find the URL for the package on github: https://github.com/sgaure/lfe (we could also get there by googling "lfe package github"). You can also go to the issues list on that repo to find [this discussion](https://github.com/sgaure/lfe/issues/41). It's long, but it looks like the maintainers are hard at work trying to get the package back on CRAN.

Not all packages have their source code/issue-tracking lists on a public site, bot those that do will generally have it listed in the `URL:` field of the `DESCRIPTION` file.

You can probably install the latest archived version via `remotes::install_version("lfe", version="2.8-5.1")` (you might need development tools [compilers etc.] installed)

Answer (score 6):

As Ben noted, the package has been resubmitted (I am one of the contributors) and should hopefully be back on CRAN soon.

But, FWIW and in the interim, I've created a simple package that takes existing `lfe::felm` scripts and converts them to the `fixest::feols` equivalent. I expect most people will move to the latter over time anyway, given its advantages. https://github.com/grantmcdermott/lfe2fixest